# JSON LD is showing an error which i cant fix

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-ld

google webmaster is showing an error on this json code

```
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "WebPage",
"url": "somelink",
"image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "somelink.png"
},
"publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "abc`entercodehere`",
    "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "somelink.png"
    }
},
"dateModified": "2019-03-2111:58:14",
"description": "Get65%offonTarget&#039;sPromos&amp;DiscountCodesOnlineatabc.FindTargetVoucherCodes2019&amp;1000sofStores&amp;othertopBrands.",
"name": "",
"headline": "TargetDiscountCodes",
"mainEntity": {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Store",
    "name": "Target",
    "image": "somelink.png",
    "description": "",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": 5,
        "reviewCount": 14
    },
    "makesOffer": [
        {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "name": "Up to 25% Off On Home at Target",
            "url": "somelink"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "name": "$5 Off $50 Select Items + Free Shipping at Target",
            "url": "somelink"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "name": "15% off Select by Calphalon at Target",
            "url": "http://dev.abc.com/target#119214"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "name": "25% off Farberware Cookware at Target",
            "url": "somelink"
        }
    ]
}
```

code above showing an error on https://json-ld.org/playground/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to quote the error message (and put it in the title). Saying that you can’t fix an error is not really helpful; what’s important is to say what kind of error you get.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a closing curly bracket "}" at the end.